# SAS if a variable = x, make all others also = x

Tags: sql, sas

I have several variables in my table, one of which is a claim number and another is a revenue code.  There are multiple lines for each unique claim number with varying revenue codes.  I want to check if a certain revenue code is present on a claim, and if so change the revenue code for all other lines with that claim number to show the same revenue code.

For example, is my table looks like:

Claim Rev_Code

123 0450

123 0762

123 0330

456 0234

I want to see that revenue code 0450 is present on claim 123, and thus change all other rows for claim 123 to show revenue code 0450.  Revenue code 0450 is not present on claim 456, so no change is made to rows with that claim number.  This is a small example, but the actual table I'm working with includes 50+ columns and 20,000,000+ rows.  Is this possible to systematically change the revenue codes in this way?  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Although Grantly's answer is doubtless valid for most flavours of SQL, the required syntax is slightly different in SAS:

```
data claims;
input claim :3. rev_code :4.;
format rev_code z4.;
cards;
123 0450
123 0762
123 0330
456 0234
;
run;

proc sql undo_policy = optional;
    update claims
    Set rev_code = 0450
    Where claim in
        (select distinct claim from claims where rev_code = 0450)
    ;
quit;
```

By default `undo_policy` is set to *required*, so SAS will refuse to process this query because it involves overwriting the variable used to determine the changes being made. I've also used `in` rather than `exists` - according to the SAS help file, this is usually more efficient.

If you create an index or two, it is also possible to update your large table via a data step, using the `modify` statement:

```
proc datasets lib = work nolist;
    modify claims;
    index create claim rev_code;
    run;
quit;

proc sql;
    create table claims_0450 as
        select distinct claim 
            from claims 
            where rev_code = 0450;
quit;

data claims;
    set claims_0450;
    do until(eof);
        modify claims key = claim end = eof;
        if _IORC_ then _ERROR_ = 0;
        else do;
            rev_code = 0450;
            replace;
        end;
    end;
run;
```

This only really requires the index on claim, but indexing rev_code as well may speed up the intermediate query. The set statement loads a claim value into the PDV from claims_0450, then the do-loop uses the index on claim to iterate through all records with that claim number and set rev_code as required. Then the next claim value is loaded into the PDV from claims_0450 and the process repeats.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find all the matching rows that have a rev_code = '0450', then now that you have all the matching rows - you can query the table again only updating the rows with a claim number in your first list, and ignoring any non matched rows.

The following query demonstrates this, with the first filtering query in the brackets.

```
Update table
Set rev_code = '0450'
Where claim_no exists in (select claim_no from table where rev_code = '0450')
```

where 'table' is your table name

Comment: If possible, please explain how your code addresses the issue, and why it works. Some users may have difficulty understanding plain code.